# What does "stark contrast" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was reading The Accidental Billionaires and I came across this sentence

> "...; the relaxed, almost rubbery way he leaned against the window - a **stark contrast** to his usual calcified, if slightly hunched posture; ...."

What does the phrase "stark contrast" mean? Thanks!

Comment: I think this is General Reference (Too Localised, here, since most people would just look it up elsewhere on the net if they didn't know the usage). Google [define stark](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=stark&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=uHNYUf61JMLU0QXy2oHgAg&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=7dac3329f46c1ced&biw=1262&bih=866) leads to *Unpleasantly or sharply clear; impossible to avoid*. It actually gives the example *his position on civil rights is in stark contrast to that of his liberal opponent*.

Comment: Hi love, welcome to ELL!  I'm glad you got an answer to your question, but in the future could you please add more information so we can understand why you're confused and help write better answers?  Perhaps you could tell us what you think it means, or what research you've done. That would make the question a better fit for the site.  Thank you, and hope to see you around the site more!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stark Contrast means "Exactly opposite of" in simple words.

The sentence means that the way in which the man leaned against the window was opposite to his usual hunched posture.